# Как реализовать чтобы картинка менялась в соответствии с названием карты?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Возник вопрос. Есть html-файл в котором идет заполнение некой формы входа в "Личный кабинет". Заполняются поля: "номер карты" и "пин", данные оттуда передаются видимо в некую базу данных. После этого идет переход в "Личный кабинет", в котором в свою очередь заполняются контактные данные. Карты 12-ти типов (как я понял висят в БД под переменной "title"). В "Личном кабинете" есть страница виртуального сертификата, в котором прописаны его контактные данные. Как реализовать чтобы  после сравнения типа карты (к примеру "title"= driver или "title"= base)  выводились картинки разных сертификатов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если title заполняется латиницей, можно просто создать картинки с именами равными тайтлам и подставлять тайтл в адрес картинки. Типа так:
`<img src="/images/<?php echo $title; ?>.jpg" alt="">`

Comment: Елки-палки дай тебе бог здоровья человече!!!  Полдня пытался выцепить эту гадость, а ларчик то вон как просто открывался. Еще раз огромное спасибо. К сожалению не могу тебе репу поднять только зарегился. нету 15 пунктов.